# Default option in SelectionCell

Tags: gwt

When I pass a string list to selectionCell, the first element will be choosen as a default value, how can I change the default value? For example at runtime I want to see the item at `index=i` as a default value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set an index in that cell

You can use only String there

```
SelectionCell statusOptionsCell = new SelectionCell(statusType);
        Column<InvitedUser, String> statusColumn = new Column<Object, String>(
                statusOptionsCell) {

            @Override
            public String getValue(Object object) {
                return object.getStatus();  //value set at runtime
            }
        };
```

And if you need array only then

```
String[] myaaray= {"one","two","three"};



  SelectionCell statusOptionsCell = new SelectionCell(statusType);
            Column<InvitedUser, String> statusColumn = new Column<Object, String>(
                    statusOptionsCell) {

                @Override
                public String getValue(Object object) {
                    return st[1];  //pass integer as i here at runtime
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Selection Cells are used in Cell widgets. So lets take CellTable as an example. In a Cell Table each row corresponds to one record ie a model/POJO. Each column corresponds to one property in the model/POJO. So, your selection cell column should be bound to one property in the model.

`Set that property's value to whatever you want as a default value before supplying that model to the Cell Table`.

Once you set the model's property its all Cell table and co's responsibility to set the value in to the selection cell.

Answer (score 0):

I have a real-life example of changing SelectionCell's value at runtime. I want to have a list of possible actions to be performed for each row. After selecting (and performing) an action I want the select to be set back to it's default value.

```
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
options.add("Choose...");
options.add("Action 1");
options.add("Action 2");

final SelectionCell cell = new SelectionCell(options);

Column<MyObject, String> column = new Column<MyObject, String>(cell) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(MyObject object) {
        return null;
    }
};

column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<MyObject, String>() {
    @Override
    public void update(final int index, MyObject object, String value) {
        // perform selected action
        // action name is stored in the `value` parameter
        // ...

        // back to default value
        cell.clearViewData(object);

        // ... or back to other value
        // cell.setViewData(object, "Action 1");

        table.redrawRow(index);
    }
});

table.addColumn(column, "Test");
```

Notice that the action is hooked-up on `update` method so it will be fired only if selected value has changed. It will never be fired with default value (`"Choose..."`).